# stanford-ner implementation in spark taking really long in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I am trying to implement stanford-ner in spark. I have tried implementing the [following](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp). I am reading extracted raw text from urls stored in Hbase as rdd, then converting them to dataframe, applying the ner as mentioned in the above link and then converting the dataframe back to rdd and writing extracted names in a new column in hbase. The code takes around 6 minutes for 1276 urls with 3 nodes and 16 cores. When run on 3 nodes with 32 cores and 120gb each for 600 000 urls, repartitions of rdd set to 1920, executor and driver memory set to 40gb each, it happens to take really long. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: I don't understand all the Spark stuff but you should be getting ~10K tokens/sec/core, and so the 6 mins timing would seem more appropriate for 3 cores than 48. Are you only running the pipeline through NER? (No parsing, etc.)

Comment: Yes,  for now I am interested only in NER and not others.

Comment: @ChristopherManning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393503/does-removing-stop-words-from-text-affect-stanford-core-nlp-ner-performance