# Does removing stop words from text affect stanford core nlp NER performance?

Tags: stanford-nlp

we are trying to implement name entity recognition on millions of comments/feedback and the process appears to be slow. We are thinking of removing stop words/frequent words from the texts and apply ner on them. Does removing stop words affect the accuracy of ner?

Comment: Performance - Definitely improved, and Accuracy - More or Less the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's plausible you will get respectable F1 scores if you run on a sentence with the stop words removed.  Ultimately you will have to experiment with it and see if the quality is acceptable for your needs.